# Specifying PDF page size with Ghostscript

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, ghostscript

I want to convert EPS files to PDF with Ghostscript while specifying the page size and orientation. I can convert the EPS file to a PDF file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.19\lib>ps2pdf D:\temp\Dmap-396.eps D:\temp\result.pdf
```

I haven't been able to change the page size or orientation though. I was trying:

```
ps2pdf D:\temp\Dmap-396.eps D:\temp\result.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=734.4 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=475.2 -dFIXEDMEDIA
```

Do you know how I can change the page size and orientation of the PDF? I'm open to other tools, particularly if they can be used with a Python script.

Ultimately I want to run this code in a Python script like what is below, but I get the error `Unrecoverable error: typecheck in .putdeviceprops`

```
from subprocess import check_output
from subprocess import call
from time import sleep

somecommand = "ps2pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=734.4 
    -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=475.2 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage 
    D:\\temp\\Dmap-396-3-9.eps D:\\temp\\result.pdf".split(" ")

call(somecommand, shell=True)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here is my working Python script:

```
from subprocess import check_output
from subprocess import call
from time import sleep
import ghostscript

somecommand = "gswin32c -o D:\\temp\\output.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=734.4 
-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=475.2 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -f D:\\temp\\Dmap.eps".split(" ")
call(somecommand, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the required media using -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS and -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS, and also set -dFIXEDMEDIA. The width/height settings you provide are, essentially, defaults; they are used until the input requests something else. If you set FIXEDMEDIA then it becomes fixed, unchangeable.

You will almost certainly **also** want to set -dPDFFitPage to scale the content so that the original media fits onto the new media. Otherwise bits of the content will fall off the new sized media.

Oh, and the order of the switches is important, they have to **precede** the input, you have them coming after the input file. Rather than use the ps2pdf shell script, use Ghostscript itself.

Comment: I changed the order of the options so that it's `ps2pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=734.4 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=475.2 -dFIXEDMEDIA D:\temp\Dmap.eps D:\temp\result.pdf`but I get the error `Unrecoverable error: typecheck in .putdeviceprops`. I'm getting this error on Windows 7, when I entered it on my Ubuntu 14.04 it runs just fine.

Comment: I added the Python script to my question that I want to get working so I can run the PDF creation.

Comment: Best to use just Ghostscript rather than the ps2pdf shell script. If for no other reason than you can see exactly what the command is. I think your problem is that the -d....POINTS expect to be integer, you can't have fractional points. Hence the typecheck error.

Comment: Cool thanks! I finally got it working. This is my final command: `gswin32c -o output.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=734.4 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=475.2 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -f Dmap.eps`